# Lost Native Dialer and Contacts App after upgrading to 4.0.3

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, contacts, phone-app, samsung-galaxy-note

I have a Samsung Galaxy Note GTN7000 Android Phone with Vodafone Connection in Mumbai.

I upgraded to 4.0.3 last Saturday after which the Phone and Contacts Icon at the Bottom disappeared.

I can't add it from App Menu either as it seems the application itself has been removed somehow.

I don't see them in the list of Application installed in ALL Tab.

Please help me restore it.

Any help is appreciated.